# Multiple Instances vs Cached Instances

Tags: java, optimization

Consider an `interface` that has only one method:

```java
Object getValue(String data);
```

Suppose this describes data transformation from a `String` to any other data type (assuming the transformation is valid). For data coming from a textual context, there may be several columns that are of the same data type and thus there would be multiple instances of the same data transformer.

A long while ago I had written code to cache these instances instead of having multiple instances of the same object:

```java
private HashMap<Class<? extends T>, T> map;

public synchronized T getInstance(Class<? extends T> type) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
  T instance = map.get(type);
  if (instance == null)
  {
    try
    {
      instance = type.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The provided class cannot be instantiated: "
              + type.getName() + "\n" + ex);
    }
    map.put(type, instance);
  }
  return instance;
}
```

Since these classes have no state, it seemed a waste, at the time to have many instances of the same class when a single shared instance would do.

However, it is likely more overhead to maintain the mapping than to have multiple instances of the same object (even though a single instance could be shared). I mean, even though there are multiple instances, the method code is only placed in memory once right? So in my mind, the JVM is effectively keeping a cache for me.

Any thoughts on the matter? Could the singleton instance-cache approach be better?

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you use `new`, you create a new object instance that is allocated in the heap. Of course, the executable code belongs to the class, which is only shared instance.

Anyway, from your text, your object have no state and you are just transforming the String parameter using no additional data. Given that, I would go for an `static` method.

Comment: Indeed, using a `static` method would be the best choice. However, there are several types of transformations and therefore several transformation classes. I didn't specifically mention this in my post. I agree that the `new` operator will allocate space on the heap; so then do you then feel that keeping a `HashMap` to provide singleton instances is a good idea? It too will consume memory; perhaps more than multiple instances, perhaps less (I suppose that will depend on how often I'm using the transformation classes). Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Tuning has no simple answers and needs a lot of data... how long are your instances going to live (if not using caches)? how often are you going to call the method? How costly is your object initialization/method processing? The cost of caching is more complicated process, a little extra memory. But maybe caching means that you are overusing memory, by keeping objects alive than otherwise would have been collected. In conclussion: Unless there is some specific reason for tuning, go for the simplest solution (no caching)

Comment: I completely agree; thank you for reminding me of this very simple, but important design strategy :)